# Скрипт для навигационного меню

Tags: html, jquery, css

JS

```
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".menu" ).hide();

$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
 $( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    $( ".hamburger" ).hide();
    $( ".cross" ).show();
});
});
```

HTML

```
    <header>

        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/header/Logo.png" alt="Snowboarding shop"></a>
        </div>


        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
        <button class="cross">&#735;</button>


        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Expirience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Expirience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <form>
            <input type="search" id="search">
            <button>
                <img src="img/header/tool.svg" alt="search">
                search
            </button>
        </form>

        <div class="shopbag">
            <img src="img/header/shoppingbag.png" alt="shopingbag">
            <p>€0</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

При нажатии на навигационное меню и увеличении масштаба страницы, меню остается и медиазапросы не помогают, помогите дописать скрипт, чтобы меню убиралось всегда?

Comment: Html часть выложите тоже, без неё не понятно.

Comment: Имею ввиду, при скролле сайта он адаптируется, но если возвращаться масштаб назад, то иконка меню остается и не убирается.

Comment: вопрос сформулирован некорректно.. После нажатия меню - переходят по ссылке в меню, а не увеличивают страницы.

Comment: Разве не возможен вариант, что по ссылкам не перейдут, а после этого проскролят экран ?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш скрипт неполный, сделал тут: при клике на гамбургер меню показать, гамбургер убрать, закрытие показать, при клике на закрытие, гамбургер показать, меню убрать.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $( ".cross" ).hide();
  $( ".menu" ).hide();

$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
 $( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    $( ".hamburger" ).hide();
    $( ".cross" ).show();
});
});
  
  $( ".cross" ).click(function(){
   $( ".hamburger" ).show(); 
    $( ".cross" ).hide();
    $( ".menu" ).hide();
  });
  
});
```

```css
button {
 width: 40px;
  height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
  <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Expirience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Expirience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос в другом. После раскрытия меню и закрытия (можно и открытым оставить, не важно) и уменьшения масштаба, кнопка меню не пропадает и путается с оригинальным меню (которое скрывается медиазапросами).

Comment: @SvArt713 ну так пропишите её сокрытие в медиазапросы.

Comment: написал, но почему-то она не убирается, скрипт значит верный, что-то с CSS ?

Comment: @SvArt713 не туда прописали вероятно.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, скрипт верен, вопрос решается с помощью установки font-size: 0 для текста кнопок, тогда при скролинге они показываться не будут.